How to run commands from a cargo crate?
I was trying to use the git-ignore-generator crate to manage .gitignore more easily, but now I am stuck as I have added the crate by cargo add and can not use the commands the crate documentation refers to. I have also tried to run cargo and just got a warning:
ignoring invalid dependency `git-ignore-generator` which is missing a lib target"

Here is my Cargo.toml file. What am I missing?

Please copy and paste your TOML file (and anything else relevant) into the question and format it as code. It will make it easier for people to help you.

You should use cargo install instead of cargo add: https://github.com/sondr3/git-ignore?tab=readme-ov-file#installation

git-ignore-generator is not a library but a installable program. If you want to install it, you have to run cargo install instead of cargo add:
cargo install git-ignore-generator

And remove it from your Cargo.toml, it should not be there.

That worked, thanks a lot!
I wonder why havent they mentioned that you have to use install and not add in the crate description.
I am just starting a project using bevy game engine, after initializing it there were over 5k changes, and as I have so far understood rust development heavily relies on using crates so I thought that I will have to modify my .gitingonre a lot and decided to look for some automated solution for it.
May be I did not get it well

What are those files? 5k for initializing a project surely means that something went wrong. Are you by any means not initializing your projects with cargo init?
Your /target directory should be in your gitignore if you would and besides that.. there aren't many files to exclude besides assets/images which you add yourself

yeah, looks like the gitignore file was not filled, sorry for that dumb question.
thank you a lot for your time and answers)
